# einstein metrics on the tangent bundle

Tags: riemannian-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, complex-geometry

hi,

i have the following question. let $M$ be a compact, real analytic, riemannian manifold with real analytic metric $g$. does the tangent bundle admit always a einstein metric ?

marco

Comment: Your question has answer no: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hitchin%E2%80%93Thorpe_inequality

Comment: This might be an interesting question, but it comes out of nowhere for me. Is there some reason why you believe that this might be the case? Is there some particular construction or approach you have in mind for obtaining the Einstein metric?

Comment: I suppose your question is ambiguous.  When you refer to the tangent bundle, are you actually referring to the bundle as-stated, or are you referring to the total space of the bundle?   

Comment: Ryan, I assumed he was asking for an Einstein metric on the total space.

Comment: actually i am refering to the following: if $M$ is a manifold as stated above (compact, riemannian , real analytic ...). Now consider the tangent bundle as a manifold $TM$ (as a new manifold). Does this manifold always carry a einstein metric? If no why exactly?

Comment: because $TM$ is not compact and the hitchin-thorpe formula does not necessary apply ?!

Comment: What about restricting to the unit tangent bundle? 

Comment: what do you mean by that ?


Comment: can you give an example, please ?

Comment: It's not known in general which manifolds admit Einstein metrics. Why should the question be easier for the total space of a tangent bundle? And you still have not said whether you want the metric to be complete or not.

Comment: do you have some counterexample using hitchin - thorpe formula? just some counterexample. or is there any, where one is considering the tangentbundle of some given manifold ?

Comment: What if you choose $X \subset TS^{2}$ as $X := \{(x,v) \in T_{x}S^{2} | g_{x}(v,v) <= 1\}$, where $g$ is some metric in $S^{2}$. How can one compute $\tau(X)$ and $\chi(X)$ (as in the hitchin-thorpe formula)? 

Comment: @marco:  You aren't going to get an obstruction that way because the tangent bundle of $S^2$ does have a (complete) Einstein metric on it, in fact, a Ricci-flat one, the Eguchi-Hansen metric.

Comment: so what would be then a counter example ?

Comment: and what about the torus, by making the same constructions as in the above post ?
